# How can I create a ConfigValue represents a object in Typesafe.Config

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-config

There is a interface in com.typesafe.config.Config:

> *Config withValue(String path, ConfigValue value);*

Suppose now I want to save an object whose class is defined by myself into the Config, what should I do？ The function ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef failed

My code looks like： 
   `val value = Resource(100)
   config.withValue("resource",
      ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(value))`

and here is the exception:

> bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: Resource(100)
>   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BugOrBroken: bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: Resource(100)
>       at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.fromAnyRef(ConfigImpl.java:275)

Comment: please describe what you have tried so far. logs and errors would help.

Comment: My code looks like:   val value = Resource(100) ；  
config.withValue("resource", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(value))；and the exception info is: bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from:Resource(100)

Comment: What jars, or what dependencies did you add to your pom.xml file in order to use `com.typesafe.config.ConfigValue`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot put arbitrary object into type safe config. If you'll go to fromAnyRef implementation you'll se that you can pass only primitives + maps. This works for me:

```
  val config = ConfigFactory.empty()

  case class Resource(i: Int)

  val value = 100
  //val value = Resource(100) // Failed 

  println(config.withValue("resource",
    ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(value)))
```

Comment: So ConfigReference.class or SimpleConfigObject.class can't work either?